# Aggregate in R keeping only a single value

Tags: r

I have a data frame I would like to aggregate, removing the rows not NA (or choosing unique rows) in the column I would like use to aggregate

i.e in the following I may want to remove every row in the data frame for which week has NA, and keep the others unmodified:

```
  OTHER_REV        month quarter year       week       date       days daysinmonth
1          2785013     1 2009 Q1 2009 2009-01-05 2009-01-05 2009-01-05          31
2          2785013     1 2009 Q1 2009 2009-01-12 2009-01-05 2009-01-05          31
3          2785013     1 2009 Q1 2009 2009-01-19 2009-01-05 2009-01-05          31
4          2785013     1 2009 Q1 2009 2009-01-26 2009-01-05 2009-01-05          31
5          2785013     1  NA QNA 2009       <NA> 2009-01-16 2009-01-16          31
6          2785013     1  NA QNA 2009       <NA> 2009-01-17 2009-01-17          31
```

Producing:

```
  OTHER_REV        month quarter year       week       date       days daysinmonth
1          2785013     1 2009 Q1 2009 2009-01-05 2009-01-05 2009-01-05          31
2          2785013     1 2009 Q1 2009 2009-01-12 2009-01-05 2009-01-05          31
3          2785013     1 2009 Q1 2009 2009-01-19 2009-01-05 2009-01-05          31
4          2785013     1 2009 Q1 2009 2009-01-26 2009-01-05 2009-01-05          31
```

I have tried using a combo of grep and unique(data$stuff), and using aggregate but neither of these approaches seemed to work.

The following is str of the data:

```
'data.frame':   1896 obs. of  34 variables:
 $ OTHER_REV      : num  2785013 2785013 2785013 2785013 2785013 ...
 $ month                 : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ quarter               :Class 'yearqtr'  num [1:1896] 2009 2009 2009 2009 NA ...
 $ year                  : num  2009 2009 2009 2009 2009 ...
 $ week                  : Date, format: "2009-01-05" "2009-01-12" "2009-01-19" "2009-01-26" ...
 $ date                  : Date, format: "2009-01-05" "2009-01-05" "2009-01-05" "2009-01-05" ...
 $ days                  : Date, format: "2009-01-05" "2009-01-05" "2009-01-05" "2009-01-05" ...
 $ daysinmonth           : int  31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 ...
```

Calling unique on df$week produces:

```
[1] "2009-01-05" "2009-01-12" "2009-01-19" "2009-01-26" NA           "2009-02-02"......
```

Comment: Try `df[!is.na(df$week),]`

Comment: If you want to remove all rows with an `NA`, then `na.omit(df)`. If you only want to omit rows with `NA` in the week column, then as akrun says.

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but `?complete.cases` is also a nice-to-know function

Comment: @user1987097 akrun's answer definitely works with the data you've provided. Can you give us more detail about what's going wrong? Any error messages?

Comment: I suspect your `NA` are not real `NA` (as R defines them) rather they are characters or factors and thus @akrun solution doesn't work. Please provide `str(df)`. Or try `df[!grepl("NA", df$week),]` and see what happens

Comment: Hi @DavidArenburg I have provided the str. The NAs in week are string NAs but I can't grep for "<na>"

Comment: I should add the NA's were produced by a merge function, and I'm guessing for some reason are applicable to those particular date classes.

Comment: Hmm.. the output of your `unique` looks like a real NA, `Date` classes don't allow character NAs like David suggests, and if they're from a `merge`, they really ought to be NAs! Peculiar. `sum(is.na(df$week))` should give you an exact count of how many true NAs are in that variable. Sorry to suggest yet another thing to post, but `dput(head(df))` would let us exactly recreate a small portion of your data to figure out what's going on (as long as `head(df)` includes some of those NAs).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
data[ ! is.na(data$week), ]
```

The similar answer using a data.table is a little simpler:

```
data[ ! is.na(week) ]
```

Comment: Going on the output it looked as though these weren't working, but assignation got the desired result!